# During an animation, can the properties of every CALayer be read atomically in the presentationLayer tree?

Tags: core-animation

I'm looking for a solution to make a video from a CoreAnimation animation.

If I recursively enumerate the sublayers of my root CALayer presentation layer, is there a risk that the values(position, transform, opacity..) keep on changing while I'm a reading the properties in the (presentation) tree ? Or is the presentation layer like a deep copy of the CALayer hierarchy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation layer is a deep copy of the model layer, with all the active animations applied. It's not actually the literal presentation tree that's used to render to screen, it's just an approximation.

Comment: Does this mean that it's not possible to get the exact values used in an animation ? I'm trying to export these value to recreate the same animation elsewhere.

Comment: @Antoine: If you want to recreate the same animation elsewhere, why are you using the presentation layer? Just use the model layer, and look at the `CAAnimation` objects on the layers.